# Is this a good way to check if a URL can be obtained via file get contents

Tags: php

```
if($url  = file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$user)){}
else die("Invalid User");
```

Is this a good way to run this script?

Comment: I would kindly suggest that you start accepting the answers to your questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean, but if you ask if your call of `file_get_contents` is correct, then I must say yes, because, as stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
On failure, file_get_contents() will return FALSE.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your code is correct, and will fill `$url` with the contents of the page, or return false if the requested URL results in an error code.  Note, however, that a page with a value of `0` or the empty string will also be [interpreted as `false`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).  To avoid this, use the strong-matching `!==`:

```
if(false !== ($url  = file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$user)))
```

If you just want to check that the URL is valid, use [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) to only fetch the headers of the response with a HTTP HEAD request:

```
stream_context_set_default(
    array(
        'http' => array(
            'method' => 'HEAD'
        )
    )
);

$headers = get_headers('http://example.com'. 1);

// get the response code
$parts = explode(' ', $headers[0]);
$code = $parts[1];

if($code == 200) ... // success
if($code == 404) ... // failure
```

This will save you from transmitting the whole page over the network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for `=== false` (note the three `=`), since empty content or content `0` would also fail the test.

Better check the HTTP status code via the [`$http_response_header` variable](http://php.net/http_response_header) - it should be in the 200 range (200-299).

Comment: Specifically, it would be `!==` here, since the invalid-user case is in the `else` block.